# What is the difference between NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads and NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

In iOS 9, I can add keys to my info.plist to disable App Transport Security.  There are two keys, `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` and `NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`, which are defined as:

> An optional Boolean value that, when set to YES, allows insecure HTTP loads. Use this key to describe your app’s intended network behavior for a domain whose security attributes you have control over.

and

> A version of the NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads key to be used to configure connections to a domain whose security attributes you don’t control.

What security attributes do they refer to?  Why does it matter what my *intentions* are?

What are the circumstances under which I'd use one of these rather than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The third party keys are deprecated by Apple as per 2016-09-13](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/RevisionHistory.html):

> Removed all mention of the following third-party-server exception keys from the description for the NSAppTransportSecurity key; Apple no longer expects apps to specify any of them: NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads, NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy, NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion.

TL;DR; use `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`.

Answer (score 1):

The two keys are functionally identical, but there is a semantic difference. I'm quoting from [this article on App Transport Security](https://cocoacasts.com/the-definitive-guide-to-app-transport-security):

> The distinction between these two keys is largely semantic, helping to clarify the **intent** and **ownership** of the domains being excepted from **ATS**'s default behavior. That said, from a technical perspective, both keys achieve the same result. They both allow insecure HTTP connections to the domain.

In summary, use `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` if you control the server/domain and use `NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` if you don't control the server/domain.

I appreciate Apple makes a distinction between the two. It is clear to the developer(s) working on the project and, also important, it is clear to Apple why the domain is excepted from **App Transport Security**. Keep in mind that Apple *can* ask you during App Review why you added an exception domain. By making it clear what the intent is (you control the domain or third-party domain), Apple has more context.